# Combined percent+pixel div layout

Tags: javascript, css, html, layout

**10 years ago I wrote a GUI layout engine in C++ and I'm curious how its functionality could be best approximated in the browser.**

### 1. C++

In older GUI libraries (like [Microsoft Windows'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), the position and size of widgets is usually given by *four* numbers: *left, top, width* and *height*. My engine is different in that each of these numbers is doubled, so you have to specify *eight* numbers: *relative left, absolute left; relative top, absolute top; relative width, absolute width; relative height* and *absolute height*. The **relative** values should be given in **percents** of the width or height of the parent widget, and the **absolute** values should be given in **pixels**. In case of top-level windows, the "parent widget" is the desktop.

Examples:

a) 400 x 300 px window, centered on screen:

```
const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300;
CWindow mainWindow;
mainWindow.setPosition(0.5, -WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, 0.5, -WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2); 
mainWindow.setSize(0.0, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0.0, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
```

b) 150 px wide button container panel at the right edge of the main window:

```
const int PANEL_WIDTH = 150;
CPanel buttonPanel(mainWindow);
buttonPanel.setPosition(1.0, -PANEL_WIDTH, 0.0, 0); 
buttonPanel.setSize(0.0, PANEL_WIDTH, 1.0, 0);
```

c) Three buttons (New, Open, Save) at the top of the container panel, and one button (Exit) at the bottom:

```
const int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 30;
CButton newButton(buttonPanel, "New");
newButton.setPosition(0.0, 0, 0.0, 0 * BUTTON_HEIGHT);
newButton.setSize(1.0, 0, 0.0, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
CButton openButton(buttonPanel, "Open");
openButton.setPosition(0.0, 0, 0.0, 1 * BUTTON_HEIGHT);
openButton.setSize(1.0, 0, 0.0, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
CButton saveButton(buttonPanel, "Save");
saveButton.setPosition(0.0, 0, 0.0, 2 * BUTTON_HEIGHT);
saveButton.setSize(1.0, 0, 0.0, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
CButton exitButton(buttonPanel, "Exit");
exitButton.setPosition(0.0, 0, 1.0, -1 * BUTTON_HEIGHT);
exitButton.setSize(1.0, 0, 0.0, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
```

Writing such layout code by hand may feel awkward when you’re new to it, but it’s easy once you get the hang of it.

### 2. HTML, CSS, JavaScript

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xE9bt/) is what I was able to hack together thus far:

a) The hierarchy of the main window, the button panel, and the buttons, is given in HTML:

```
<div id="mainWindow">
    <div id="buttonPanel">
        <div id="newButton" class="button"></div>
        <div id="openButton" class="button"></div>
        <div id="saveButton" class="button"></div>
        <div id="exitButton" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

b) The divs' position is set to absolute in CSS:

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body { margin: 0; color: yellow; }
#mainWindow { position: absolute; background: red; }
#buttonPanel { position: absolute; background: green; }
.button { border: 1px solid cyan; }
#newButton { position: absolute; background: blue; }
#openButton { position: absolute; background: blue; }
#saveButton { position: absolute; background: blue; }
#exitButton { position: absolute; background: blue; }
```

c) The layout functionality is implemented in JavaScript, using jQuery:

```
function setPosition(widget, relLeft, absLeft, relTop, absTop) {
    $(widget)
        .css('left', relLeft * 100 + '%').css('left', '+=' + absLeft + 'px')
        .css('top', relTop * 100 + '%').css('top', '+=' + absTop + 'px');
}

function setSize(widget, relWidth, absWidth, relHeight, absHeight) {
    $(widget)
        .css('width', relWidth * 100 + '%').css('width', '+=' + absWidth + 'px')
        .css('height', relHeight * 100 + '%').css('height', '+=' + absHeight + 'px');
}

function setButtonText(button, text, height) {
    $(button)
        .text(text)
        .css('text-align', 'center')
        .css('vertical-align', 'middle')
        .css('line-height', height + 'px');
}

window.onresize = function () {
    var WINDOW_WIDTH = 400,
        WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300,
        PANEL_WIDTH = 150,
        BUTTON_HEIGHT = 30;

    setPosition('#mainWindow', 0.5, -WINDOW_WIDTH / 2, 0.5, -WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2);
    setSize('#mainWindow', 0.0, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0.0, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    setPosition('#buttonPanel', 1.0, -PANEL_WIDTH, 0.0, 0);
    setSize('#buttonPanel', 0.0, PANEL_WIDTH, 1.0, 0);
    setButtonText('#newButton', "New", BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    setPosition('#newButton', 0.0, 0, 0.0, 0 * BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    setSize('#newButton', 1.0, 0, 0.0, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    setButtonText('#openButton', "Open", BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    setPosition('#openButton', 0.0, 0, 0.0, 1 * BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    setSize('#openButton', 1.0, 0, 0.0, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    setButtonText('#saveButton', "Save", BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    setPosition('#saveButton', 0.0, 0, 0.0, 2 * BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    setSize('#saveButton', 1.0, 0, 0.0, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    setButtonText('#exitButton', "Exit", BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    setPosition('#exitButton', 0.0, 0, 1.0, -1 * BUTTON_HEIGHT);
    setSize('#exitButton', 1.0, 0, 0.0, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
};

onresize();
```

Note that the JavaScript code is very similar to the C++ code shown above!

### My question

Is this JavaScript-based layout acceptable to build a "real" web application, or should I use CSS instead? Since I'm basically a desktop app developer, I need expert web developer opinion. Thanks!

**=== UPDATE ===**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xE9bt/5/) is a pure HTML+CSS solution. I used the negative margin trick suggested by @Christoph. My only problem is that the same constants are copied to lots of places in the CSS. For example, button height (30px) is used in *nine* places, which makes maintenance much harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, inline css (css attached via `style=""`) is considered a bad choice. Since you generate this dynamically via a script it might be acceptable.

However, there are some problems:

1. Generally, absolute positioning should be used as sparingly as possible.
2. There is definitely no need to alter the layout in `window.onresize`. This event should be used with extreme caution. As you can see in the fiddle, your example UI is rather small, but already becoming unresponsive on resizing the window. (And those values in your example are static anyway)

So my hint is to:

1. Use some kind of `init()` method where you do the initial layouting
2. avoid `window.onresize` or at least use some timeout mechanism to reduce the triggering of those paint events ([reduce number of calls for .resize and .scroll methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420853/reduce-number-of-calls-for-resize-and-scroll-methods))
3. perhaps instead of jQuery's `css()` calls, write the css for your elements in a [separate stylesheet](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html).
4. best solution: generate the html and css markup serverside and serve the final html+css to the browser. advantages: faster rendering + maintainable + you get a cacheable stylesheet and html

Comment: 1. "absolute positioning should be used as sparingly as possible" - Why? Does it decrease performance? 2. Onresize is needed to keep #mainWindow centered. Load this page, and move the sliders around the Result panel: http://jsfiddle.net/zdVtB/ 3. I agree, maybe I should really avoid JS layout and generate CSS in server-side code.

Comment: take a look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xE9bt/1/ no resize event, still centered. Centering is achieved with the css-rule for `#mainWindow`. Also, absolute positioning causes a reflow each time an element is positioned.

Comment: @kol also interesting might be the new [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) Method for you.

Comment: Wow.. calc does exactly what I need! Like this: width: calc(100% - 80px); Is there a replacement for older browsers? I would definitely like to use calc but I need something for the chaps having IE8 or older.

Comment: @kol take a look at the `#mainWindow` rule in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xE9bt/1/ - you can use the negative margin trick for those old browsers.

Comment: Just one more question: Do you need "position: absolute;" for the negative margin trick? You (and others) suggested not using it, but if I set it to "relative", the "top:50%" setting stops working: http://jsfiddle.net/xE9bt/3/

Comment: @kol yes, absolute positioning is required for that. You can use position absolute - no problem with that. It just requires some caution .

Answer (score 2):

It will always be easier and, performance wise, faster to set **initial** values with CSS. Setting everything to absolute can work but, depending on the application, can become a layout nightmare since absolutely positioned elements are removed from the normal flow.

While I see where you're coming from, having once coded graphical apps for the desktop, you'll find it doesn't work as well for the web unless you're expecting a fixed layout where layout performance isn't crucial.

But then, I'm thinking along the lines of layout in today's world where you have a multitude of devices in all shapes and sizes you need to adapt to. On the one hand, it could be easier to control all that using javascript, and many times it is the best way, but, otoh, CSS can handle a lot of that with media queries to take the burden off you and your coding.

It's a lot to think about.

Comment: "can become a layout nightmare" - Why? If I use my approach for the whole web app, it should work, shouldn't it? Do you mean it could clash with 3rd party code?

Comment: That's what I meant by the elements being removed from the normal flow. You can do what you show but my concern would be whether you would regret it later when you add third-party code or anything else; what clashes would there be? The first relatively positioned element you place on this will overlap all your absolutely positioned ones. When someone resizes their browser, is it OK if the page slides off to the side where you don't see it? Things to think about but I'm not saying it won't work.

Comment: Your way of doing things is only relevant if you go for a tool like create.js. Otherwise, go for the web way :)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer :

THIS IS BAD ! NEVER DO THAT.

Long answer :

This is not the way the web is supposed to work. Your application won't perform great because css rules will wait for the js to be downloaded and interpreted ; but this is not the main concern here. The main concerne is about you.

You will never be able to maintain a code like this one. When you build a simple application, you can easily go to a few thousands css rules. Impossible to read if organized this way. And I don't even mention the media queries stuff. The complexity of an app build this way would be way too high.

If you wanna go for the web, you have to embrace the web ; not to try your old desktop pplication developper tricks (which are greats for desktop application). For instance, if you want to put something in the top right corner, your go for : `right: 0`. Not `WINDOW_WIDTH`; if your ant to center somethin, you have many ways to do so ; but you don't make math for the position. Never ever do that.

---

As a webapplication developper, my advice is this one :

Go use compass : http://compass-style.org/

Actually no, go use Yeoman : http://yeoman.io/

Thoses tools are a bit complex to fully understand ; but it worth it soooo much.

---

Btw, never bind an `onresize`event like that. You have to add a `debounce` otherwise you will meet serious performances troubles.

Comment: I disagree in the following points: 1) If the css is generated you don't need to maintain it. In fact it is easier - you just need to maintain the generator functions. 2) calculating was and always is essential in css. That's why they even introduced [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

Comment: `calc()` is a very new thing ; did not event work in safari 5. Generated content does not mean you don't have to maintain it. How will he manage the vendor prefixes ? He won't use the great tools we have and do everything from scratch... This is madness :) How many lines of code to generate a simple css file like this one : http://s2.wp.com/wp-content/themes/h4/style.css?m=1366305803g&7 ?

Comment: the fact that it's new proves my point even more... there has always been the need of calculations and now you have even new attribute to take this into account. And you don't need to maintain generated code, if you want to adapt it, you just re-generate it. Vendor-prefixes? Even easier with generators - take a look at sass or less or prefix-free. You write the standards code and the rest will be created automatically for you with help of mixins or whatever. The cool thing about generators is that after the effort of initially implementing them, you can create stuff in seconds without thinking

Comment: Thanks for your answer, especially for mentioning debouncing. Anyway, I don't think my code is unmaintainable. On the contrary, it's pretty simple. It seems easier to maintain than the equivalent CSS, since (1) constants are defined only once, and (2) the layout of every widget is defined the same way, while the CSS version is much more heterogenous. In spite of all these, I agree with you and others: CSS layout is probably more efficient than any kind of JavaScript layout. It's just that I'm used to imperative programming, and declarative stuff like CSS are a bit alien :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm definitely not an expert, but here are my 2 cents :

Using JavaScript for your design is and has always been fine. But in order to do so, you need to also have some static CSS also, for all those people that don't have JavaScript enabled, for matters of accessibility and such.

Javascript design has always been about enhancing you web application, and never about replacing it. You definitely should have a look to this Wikipedia page about [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Coming back to your question, why not making your buttons have a fixed size by default, and let your JavaScript functionality replace it when avalaible ?

Also, what I'm not getting in your web application is that here, everything could have been done in CSS, and way faster. It would have had better performance, and you wouldn't even have to worry about JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Web development has its own philosophy, and I definitely have to embrace it before doing some serious web coding :)

Comment: "everything could have been done in CSS" - How? Would you please give me some CSS which implements this "combined percent + pixel layout model"?